# Kotlin: Using map and reduce, generate a random list of colours

Tags: kotlin, range

I've been given

```
val c = arrayOf("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange",
"white", "black")
```

and need to generate and print a list of 50 random colours, using range and map. 
And I want to use map to translate numbers to the colours and print the result.
Could I get some help on this?

Comment: You don't need the map if already have the array of colors, just shuffle them:
```kotlin
val shuffledColorsList = arrayOf("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange",
        "white", "black")
        .toList()
        .shuffled()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the 'range + map' approach you can use the function [`List`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list.html) that takes the number of elements in list and the element initializer function:

```
val c = arrayOf("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange",
"white", "black")

// create a list of 50 elements initializing each to a random element of 'c' array 
val random50 = List(50) { c.random() }

// print results
random50.forEach { println(it) }
```

If you still prefer range and map, the equivalent would be to create a range of 50 elements, e.g. `1..50` and then call `map` on that range:

```
(1..50).map { c.random() }
```

Comment: I am required to use range and mapping, I know it's not the most effective.

Comment: I'm curious, where does this constraint come from? Is it a homework or assignment of some sort?

Comment: You got me, indeed it is a homework assignment, I've done some previous tasks with ranging and mapping I just can't get this to work like I want it to

Comment: For future reference please read the StackOverflow community policy about asking homework questions here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823